# OSPF - default-information originate : multiple routers

Tags: networking, cisco

[image: basic network]

I receive a default route via iBGP from R1. On both R2 and R3 I have default-information originate configured. On R4 I only see one default route in the OSPF database; either to R2 or R3. When I shutdown one of the links from R2 / R3 to R1, I see the other default route appear in the OSPF database.

My real topology is a bit more complex, so is it possible to have both default routes appear on R4 without default-information originate always? I want the default route being advertised on R2 / R3 to be reliant on the default route from R1 existing in the RIB.

Thanks

Edit: add configs and output

R1

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 10.0.1.1/30
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 10.0.1.5/30
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 10.1.1.1/30
set interfaces lo0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.1.3/32
...
set routing-options static route 0.0.0.0/0 discard
set routing-options autonomous-system 65535
set protocols bgp group internal type internal
set protocols bgp group internal bfd-liveness-detection minimum-interval 300
set protocols bgp group internal bfd-liveness-detection multiplier 3
set protocols bgp group internal neighbor 10.0.1.2 export default-originate
set protocols bgp group internal neighbor 10.0.1.6 export default-originate
set protocols ospf export ospf-default
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/2.0
set protocols bfd traceoptions file bfd-trace
set protocols bfd traceoptions flag all
```

R2

```
redundancy
 bfd-template single-hop BGP-BFD
 interval min-tx 300 min-rx 300 multiplier 3
 dampening 2 1000 3000 8
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address 10.0.1.2 255.255.255.252
 negotiation auto
 bfd template BGP-BFD
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 ip address 10.0.1.9 255.255.255.252
 negotiation auto
 bfd template BGP-BFD
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet3.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.1.13 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet3.300
 encapsulation dot1Q 300
 ip address 10.0.1.21 255.255.255.252
!
router ospf 110
 network 10.0.1.9 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.1.13 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.1.21 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 default-information originate
!
router bgp 65535
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 bgp redistribute-internal
 redistribute ospf 110
 neighbor 10.0.1.1 remote-as 65535
 neighbor 10.0.1.1 fall-over bfd
 neighbor 10.0.1.10 remote-as 65535
 neighbor 10.0.1.10 fall-over bfd
!
```

R3

```
redundancy
bfd-template single-hop BGP-BFD
 interval min-tx 300 min-rx 300 multiplier 3
 dampening 2 1000 3000 8
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address 10.0.1.6 255.255.255.252
 negotiation auto
 bfd template BGP-BFD
!         
interface GigabitEthernet2
 ip address 10.0.1.10 255.255.255.252
 negotiation auto
 bfd template BGP-BFD
!         
interface GigabitEthernet3
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!         
interface GigabitEthernet3.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 10.0.1.17 255.255.255.252
!         
interface GigabitEthernet3.400
 encapsulation dot1Q 400
 ip address 10.0.1.25 255.255.255.252
!         
router ospf 110
 network 10.0.1.10 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.1.17 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.1.25 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.1.2 0.0.0.0 area 0
 default-information originate
!         
router bgp 65535
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 bgp redistribute-internal
 redistribute ospf 110
 neighbor 10.0.1.5 remote-as 65535
 neighbor 10.0.1.5 fall-over bfd
 neighbor 10.0.1.9 remote-as 65535
 neighbor 10.0.1.9 fall-over bfd
!
```

R4

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 192.168.1.4 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.1.14 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 10.0.1.18 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.0.0
 negotiation auto
!
router ospf 110
 network 10.0.1.14 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.1.18 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 172.16.0.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.1.4 0.0.0.0 area 0
!
```

R5

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 192.168.1.5 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.300
 encapsulation dot1Q 300
 ip address 10.0.1.22 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet1.400
 encapsulation dot1Q 400
 ip address 10.0.1.26 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
router ospf 110
 network 10.0.1.22 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.1.26 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 192.168.1.5 0.0.0.0 area 0
!
```

R4 - Output

```
R4# sho ip ospf database 

            OSPF Router with ID (192.168.1.4) (Process ID 110)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
192.168.1.1     192.168.1.1     1219        0x80000005 0x007AA3 4
192.168.1.2     192.168.1.2     1218        0x80000005 0x008881 4
192.168.1.4     192.168.1.4     1223        0x80000003 0x00B0D9 4
192.168.1.5     192.168.1.5     1219        0x80000003 0x0071C3 3

                Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.1.10       192.168.1.2     1230        0x80000001 0x006F74
10.0.1.14       192.168.1.4     1223        0x80000001 0x004F8C
10.0.1.18       192.168.1.4     1223        0x80000001 0x0035A1
10.0.1.22       192.168.1.5     1219        0x80000001 0x0003CE
10.0.1.26       192.168.1.5     1219        0x80000001 0x00E8E3

                Type-5 AS External Link States

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     1217        0x80000001 0x00CD0B 110
```

R5 - Output

```
R5#sho ip ospf database 

            OSPF Router with ID (192.168.1.5) (Process ID 110)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
192.168.1.1     192.168.1.1     473         0x80000006 0x0078A4 4
192.168.1.2     192.168.1.2     503         0x80000006 0x008682 4
192.168.1.4     192.168.1.4     451         0x80000004 0x00AEDA 4
192.168.1.5     192.168.1.5     471         0x80000004 0x006FC4 3

                Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.1.10       192.168.1.2     503         0x80000002 0x006D75
10.0.1.14       192.168.1.4     451         0x80000002 0x004D8D
10.0.1.18       192.168.1.4     451         0x80000002 0x0033A2
10.0.1.22       192.168.1.5     471         0x80000002 0x0001CF
10.0.1.26       192.168.1.5     471         0x80000002 0x00E6E4

                Type-5 AS External Link States

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     503         0x80000002 0x00CB0C 110
```

R2 BGP / OSPF

```
BGP table version is 15, local router ID is 192.168.1.1
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal, 
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, f RT-Filter, 
              x best-external, a additional-path, c RIB-compressed, 
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
RPKI validation codes: V valid, I invalid, N Not found

     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 r>i 0.0.0.0          10.0.1.1                      100      0 i
 * i 10.0.1.8/30      10.0.1.10                0    100      0 ?
 *>                   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 * i 10.0.1.12/30     10.0.1.18                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  10.0.1.16/30     10.0.1.14                2         32768 ?
 * i                  10.0.1.10                0    100      0 ?
 * i 10.0.1.20/30     10.0.1.26                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  10.0.1.24/30     10.0.1.22                2         32768 ?
 * i                  10.0.1.10                0    100      0 ?
 * i 172.16.0.0       10.0.1.18                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   10.0.1.14                2         32768 ?
 *>  192.168.1.1/32   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 * i 192.168.1.2/32   10.0.1.10                0    100      0 ?
*>                   10.0.1.10                2         32768 ?
 * i 192.168.1.4/32   10.0.1.18                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   10.0.1.14                2         32768 ?
 * i 192.168.1.5/32   10.0.1.26                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   10.0.1.22                2         32768 ?

  Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
192.168.1.1     192.168.1.1     736         0x8000002D 0x002ACB 4
192.168.1.2     192.168.1.2     923         0x8000002D 0x0038A9 4
192.168.1.4     192.168.1.4     1263        0x8000002B 0x006002 4
192.168.1.5     192.168.1.5     912         0x8000002B 0x0021EB 3

                Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.1.10       192.168.1.2     923         0x80000029 0x001F9C
10.0.1.14       192.168.1.4     1263        0x80000029 0x00FEB4
10.0.1.18       192.168.1.4     1263        0x80000029 0x00E4C9
10.0.1.22       192.168.1.5     912         0x80000029 0x00B2F6
10.0.1.26       192.168.1.5     912         0x80000029 0x00980C

                Type-5 AS External Link States

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     178         0x80000001 0x00CD0B 110
```

R3 BGP / OSPF

```
BGP table version is 17, local router ID is 192.168.1.2
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal, 
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, f RT-Filter, 
              x best-external, a additional-path, c RIB-compressed, 
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
RPKI validation codes: V valid, I invalid, N Not found

     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>i 0.0.0.0          10.0.1.5                      100      0 i
 * i 10.0.1.8/30      10.0.1.9                 0    100      0 ?
 *>                   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  10.0.1.12/30     10.0.1.18                2         32768 ?
 * i                  10.0.1.9                 0    100      0 ?
 * i 10.0.1.16/30     10.0.1.14                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 *>  10.0.1.20/30     10.0.1.26                2         32768 ?
 * i                  10.0.1.9                 0    100      0 ?
 * i 10.0.1.24/30     10.0.1.22                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 * i 172.16.0.0       10.0.1.14                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   10.0.1.18                2         32768 ?
 * i 192.168.1.1/32   10.0.1.9                 0    100      0 ?
     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>                   10.0.1.9                 2         32768 ?
 * i 192.168.1.2/32   10.0.1.9                 2    100      0 ?
 *>                   0.0.0.0                  0         32768 ?
 * i 192.168.1.4/32   10.0.1.14                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   10.0.1.18                2         32768 ?
 * i 192.168.1.5/32   10.0.1.22                2    100      0 ?
 *>                   10.0.1.26                2         32768 ?

OSPF Router with ID (192.168.1.2) (Process ID 110)

                Router Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Link count
192.168.1.1     192.168.1.1     944         0x8000002D 0x002ACB 4
192.168.1.2     192.168.1.2     1129        0x8000002D 0x0038A9 4
192.168.1.4     192.168.1.4     1470        0x8000002B 0x006002 4
192.168.1.5     192.168.1.5     1119        0x8000002B 0x0021EB 3

                Net Link States (Area 0)

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum
10.0.1.10       192.168.1.2     1129        0x80000029 0x001F9C
10.0.1.14       192.168.1.4     1470        0x80000029 0x00FEB4
10.0.1.18       192.168.1.4     1470        0x80000029 0x00E4C9
10.0.1.22       192.168.1.5     1119        0x80000029 0x00B2F6
10.0.1.26       192.168.1.5     1119        0x80000029 0x00980C

                Type-5 AS External Link States

Link ID         ADV Router      Age         Seq#       Checksum Tag
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     384         0x80000001 0x00CD0B 110
```

Comment: Can you share configurations and output of relevant `show` commands?

Comment: Ugh - sorry, I was hoping to keep it as simple as possible because I was hoping it was something obvious, but; I added an additional switch R5 to emulate another distro switch (same as R4).  R1 is actually a Juniper SRX.  Essentially the question boils down to 'why can't I use default-information originate - E2, on two routers and have both advertise default routes?  Only one or the other does'?  When I kill the BGP on the router advertising the default into OSPF, the other takes over, but I want both... ( relevant configs and outputs attached )

Comment: Can you show the BGP and OSPF tables for `R2` and `R3` as well?

Comment: I've added the outputs for clarity; by you asking the right questions, I was able to step back and answer it myself.  If I could figure out how to give you some points for your comment, I would, but I can't see how to give points to a comment instead of a reply.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first router (out of R2 / R3) to redistribute the default route from iBGP into OSPF will be the only default route that OSPF puts into the database.  I noticed that whichever router is second to try to redistribute the default route into OSPF will encounter a BGP RIB failure because the default route from the other router is already installed into the RIB by OSPF and is pointing to the other router.  I've read that routes from BGP will not be redistributed into another protocol if the route is not in the routing table.